# Azure login error

Tags: azure, authentication

I have an organizational service account which is not able to **login to Azure** through `XPlat-Cli`

```
Command in .ps1 script        
[string]$results = azure login -u $user -p $securepwd 

Where $User is abc@MyOrganization.com (This Account has required access to azure subscription)
$securepwd - Account valid password
```

Logs:

```
VERBOSE: Login details provided through parameters.
error: No HOME path available
VERBOSE: info: Error information has been recorded to azure.err
```

I Couldn't be able to figure out the issue here. need help for this.

Comment: $HOME is set on the machine where script is getting executed.

Comment: I'm a bit confused why you're invoking the Azure XPlat CLI from within PowerShell. Why not just use PowerShell top to bottom? Is the account you are using a Microsoft Account or an Organisational Account (from AD)?

Comment: We need to deploy Azure Website using Xplat-Cli and there fore we are using Xplat-Cli commands in Powershell. And the account is an organizational account.

Comment: Understand, but you do have the equivalent commands in the PowerShell Cmdlets. Regardless, check to ensure you're using the right subscription ('azure account list' to show and then 'azure account set' to set the default subscription if you have more than one).

Comment: Does the `azure login` command work from command line?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I could able to fix this by altering the util.js file installed as part of Xplat-Cli at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI\lib\util          added  -- return process.env.USERPROFILE; after  --process.env.HOME

Comment: And to answer the question from   user272735 : I was able to login manually using the same organizational account with azure login